# getSupportActionBar() returns null in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm trying to attach a map view to a fragment in a tab.

This is my MapFragment:

```
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class MapFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private static final String KEY_STATE_BUNDLE = "localActivityManagerState";

    private LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;

    protected LocalActivityManager getLocalActivityManager() {
        return mLocalActivityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle state = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            state = savedInstanceState.getBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE);
        }

        mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), true);
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(state);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //This is where you specify you activity class
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationActivity.class); 
        Window w = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("tag", i); 
        View currentView=w.getDecorView(); 
        currentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        currentView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
        ((ViewGroup) currentView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        return currentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE,
                mLocalActivityManager.saveInstanceState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchPause(getActivity().isFinishing());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchDestroy(getActivity().isFinishing());
    }
}
```

This is my LocationActivity:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;



/*
 * A location activity that defers location and map functionality to the app. This activity can be used directly but an activity have to send lon/lat when they do the intent call. 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)
 */
public class LocationActivity extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockMapActivity {


/*t
 * Variables for this activity. 
 */
    private MapView mapView;
    private GeoPoint newP, mapOverlayP, myLocationP,p,markedP;
    private boolean pointset = false, markset = false, point = false, markerpoint = false;
    private ArrayList<String> address =  new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Double> lon = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private ArrayList<Double> lat = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private String markedAddr = null,setAddr = null;

    private MapController mc;
    private double latitude, longitude, Lon, Lat;
    private ArrayList<LocationDb> locations = new ArrayList<LocationDb>();
    LocationDb locationDb = new LocationDb();
    private Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location,lastLocation,myLocation;

    long minTime = 3;
    float bestAccuracy =1;
    Location bestResult;
    long bestTime = 0;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    public ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();
    ListView  placesListView;
    Button expandListButton;
    public static EditText searchText;
    @Override
    public void onStart(){

        final View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_title, null);
        final TextView customNavHeader = (TextView) customNav.findViewById(R.id.actionbarHeader);
        customNavHeader.setText("Done");
        customNavHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              onClick_addLocation();
            }
        }); //e

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.map);

      mapView =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView1);

      expandListButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.expandListButton);
      new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);


      placesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.explorePlacesListView);
      // Define a listener that responds to location updates
       locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location
            // provider.
            // makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
            getLonLat(location);


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
      };

      getLocation();

      //handler = new Handler();

     // bundle = (Bundle) getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("bundle");

      bundle = null;
      if (bundle != null)
      { 
      getLocation();

      }
      checkLocation();
      if(myLocationP != null)
      {
      addMyLocationMarker(myLocationP);
      }

      if(markset)
      {
      addLocationMarker(newP);
      }

      new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),  (int) (longitude * 1E6));

    //Menu

      placesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {


              latitude = Double.valueOf(places.get(position).latitude);
              longitude = Double.valueOf(places.get(position).longitude);
              newP = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),  (int) (longitude * 1E6));
              markedP = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),  (int) (longitude * 1E6));
              markedAddr = places.get(position).name;
              setAddr = places.get(position).name;
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), markedAddr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              addLocationMarker(newP);
              pointset = false;

          }
        });



      expandListButton.setText("Searching..");
  }
```

Just not able to attach it to the fragment. Where am I going wrong?

Also, is this the best way to go about it? Can't I just attach it in the fragment itself rather than calling another activity? If so, how?

Comment: Can you put the whole code for the LocationActivity please? Including the imports and global variables declarations.

Comment: Have edited. But I doubt it will help you much. All I want is a basic map view to be up. Everything else(mapping locations) and all that are just function calls. I don't think I need to call a separate activity for that. So, is it possible to do it without all that?

Comment: your question says the support action bar returns null, where is your `null` thrown?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

I believe `SherlockMapActivity` extends `MapActivity` which does not have an `ActionBar`

Whatever you are doing I highly recommend you to look at [version 2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) of Maps for android and use that instead.

I also think `SherlockMapActivity` has been removed from ABS. ([source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app))